# Using FinancialData to obtain historical data on NASDAQ closing prices

Tags: curated-data, finance

I have been struggling for over an hour, reading documentation, experimenting, google searching for information on how to ask for the closing price of the NASDAQ index.  I don't want a stock on that index, I want the daily closing prices of the index itself.  No stock name, no entity, no entity class that I have tried seems to work.  Is this even possible?

Comment: According to the documentation, this should work `FinancialData["^IXIC"]` but it does not. There are a lot of issues with `FinancialData`. e.g. see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215344/58370).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi  -- yes, I tried that and other variations.  Some of those seems to be known quantities but nothing is produced reported by Missing[NotAvailable].  But, for others an error is produced saying that the entity name, class, etc. is not known.  I have had problems with FinancialData before, enough that for awhile I went directly to Yahoo via Python/SQL scripts which seemed to work better but definitely not nice as if it were integrated into Mathematica.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: [Financial data from Quandl in Wolfram Language using QuandlLink](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/540228)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov -- Thanks, got the link booked to read tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Tickers with a caret don't always work. But I think your post from 2020 is moot now, FinancialData["^IXIC"] works just fine in 13.3 on Linux.

I find the Yahoo Finance data API quite reliable and fast, have a look at

```
now=Round@AbsoluteTime[Date[]]-AbsoluteTime[{1970,1,1,0,0,0}];
Import["https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/^IXIC?period1=1410825600&period2="<>ToString[now]<>"&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 13.1 this works:

```
(* get timeseries *)
nasdaq = FinancialData["^IXIC", "Close", {{2018, 1, 1}, {2022, 11, 03}}];
```

To get the daily closing prices you can do `nasdaq["Values"]`

You can also opreate directly on the `TimeSeries`

```
(*check most recent data*)
nasdaq["LastDate"] (* DateObject[{2022, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.]*)
nasdaq["LastValue"] (* 10524.8 *)

(*annualised vol*)
16*StandardDeviation@Differences@Log@nasdaq (* 0.267453 *)

(*eye ball your data*)
DateListPlot[nasdaq]
```

> [image: Nasdaq]