# Apart from Wolfram language, what other systems provide similar structured ways to access curated data?

Tags: curated-data

Wolfram Language has chosen their Entity Framework by which they provide end-users access to the data they have accumulated. Are there similar examples of languages and system that have created or are creating a rich language to work with curated data?

Recently I was looking at how Microsoft is building their ["Linked Data Types"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbImc7A8_Q8) for Excel (another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgl7UG8UF8A)). They are promising 100s of curated data types in their recent promotional [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SkHWXH49js&t=748) for Office 365. Some of the examples are very similar to Wolfram Entities like Financial, GeoEntites and Food. I wonder if their coverage of Financial data is more comprehensive than `FinancialData` in Wolfram language which seems to be on the decline in recent [versions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215344/is-financialdata-about-to-be-depreciated) and frequent [timeout issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215558/what-is-the-current-wolframalpha-server-capacity). If big players like Microsoft are jumping into ways of providing end-user hassle-free access to curated data then they can provide a serious challenge to data behind EntityFramework.

If someone has been using these `Linked Data Types` or other technologies, comment on the quality of data that exist currently. I had Office 365 subscription but didn't know about these data types but will also look into how they compare with what is available in Wolfram language. With Excel's array language being implemented at its engine level with ["Dynamic Arrays"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hO0g1wK6u4) and the introduction of cell level variable scoping constructs like LET, does appear to be addressing a lot of spreadsheet issues which make people in data science switch to high-level programming languages like python (pandas) and WL (Entities and Dataset).

---

Excel is now inching closer and closer to being a Turing-complete functional language competitor. With [Lambda](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-turn-excel-formulas-into-custom-functions/ba-p/1925546) now it is possible to define custom anonymous functions.

Nevermind Microsoft has [partnered](https://www.wolframalpha.com/microsoft-integration/excel) with Wolfram to take their data into their Excel Linked Data Types as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a WL-related question.

Comment: @RolfMertig I understand your point but if there are technologies that are replicating WL's features, then being able to compare them and seeing where WL stand is very much a WL-related question.

Comment: Any comparison discussion would likely be a very much a matter of opinion and not appropriate to this site,